# How to check if the Auto-renewable subscription active? Or: MKStoreKit's purchase record is always Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I need to implement In App Purchasing of Auto-renewable subscription in my app and using MKStoreKit v 6 for this purpose. The app successfully makes a purchase in a test account, but in property `purchaseRecord` I always have `null` against my product's ID. This is the output of `purchaseRecord`:

```
purchaseRecord: {
SKOrigBundleRef = "1.0";
"com.cName.aName.AutoSubscription" = "<null>";
}
```

Because of it, `MKStoreKit`'s method `expiryDateForProduct:` always crashes.

Also, method `isProductPurchased:` always returns `YES`, independently whether the subscription active or expired.

How to check if the Auto-renewable Subscription expired or no using `MKStoreKit` or without it? In this case I can just write my own method to check it.
I'll be very appriciate if you give an example code.

Thank you very much in advance!